# Downloaded a Firefox Addon on addons.mozilla.COM. Ignored Untrusted Certificate. Should I worry?

Tags: firefox, https, ssl-certificate

This site:

https://en-us.add-ons.mozilla.com

has an untrusted certificate. (At least with my browser: Iceweasel 24.2.0)
I find that highly suspicious. 
But I do not know enough about such certificates to be sure.

Can someone enlighten me?

*EDIT*:
To clarify, this question is about: Does this only happen to me and I probably downloaded an addon from a Man in the Middle or is it normal and I have downloaded that addon from a trusted site?
The Answer seems to be, that it probably was ok. Mozilla did not include that specific subdomain in their certificate. (Still strange, but ... ok)

Comment: What message does it give you? Chrome nicely tells you what you're getting: *"You attempted to reach en-us.add-ons.mozilla.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as addons.mozilla.org"*, so I'd simply have gone to http://addons.mozilla.org instead.

Comment: Its a mozilla.com sub-domain so its perfectly safe.  I am not saying the certificate shouldn't be valid but unless your a victim of a MiTM attack its perfectly safe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, *in this case* you do not need to worry. Your download was taken from the very same server, owned by the Mozilla Foundation. Don't trust on that next time though!

How can you tell you were safe today? When using Chrome, you nicely get:

> You attempted to reach en-us.add-ons.mozilla.com, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as addons.mozilla.org.

When going to https://addons.mozilla.org you'll see it *looks* the same. Web servers can respond to multiple domains with the very same content. But of course, someone could have copied the look and feel to another server. Luckily, in your case [you can tell](http://www.digwebinterface.com/?hostnames=addons.mozilla.org%0D%0Aen-us.add-ons.mozilla.com&type=&ns=resolver&useresolver=8.8.4.4) both domains refer to the very same server, (today) using IP address 63.245.216.132 for IPv4:

```
$ host addons.mozilla.org
addons.mozilla.org is an alias for addons.dynect.mozilla.net.
addons.dynect.mozilla.net has address 63.245.216.132
addons.dynect.mozilla.net has IPv6 address 2620:101:8020:5::2:132
```

```
$ host en-us.add-ons.mozilla.com
en-us.add-ons.mozilla.com is an alias 
    for addons-mozilla-org.mktns.services.phx1.mozilla.net.
addons-mozilla-org.mktns.services.phx1.mozilla.net has address 63.245.216.132
```

So, despite ignoring the warning, *in this case* you downloaded from the expected server.

Certificates are all based on trust: you trust your browser, your browser trusts a few "certificate authorities", and those sell certificates to website owners. For better trust, the certificate authority should have asked for some proof that the domain(s) are indeed owned by the buyer. (If they don't, then if someone is able to mess with [DNS servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_server) *and* could buy a certificate for a domain they don't really own, then they might fool your browser into accepting that without any warning. In case of Mozilla, it's even an [Extended Validation Certificate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate), so trust is high.)

And most importantly: website owners know they should keep the secret parts of their certificates very secure. Without that secret part, another website cannot use someone else's certificate. So, `en-us.add-ons.mozilla.com` cannot show a certificate that says it's `addons.mozilla.org`, unless the secrets were compromised, or unless the two websites simply have the same owner or even refer to the very same server.

So, unless trust of *both* DNS and the certificate were somehow compromised: if a server tells your browser that it is known as `addons.mozilla.org`, then such is true. In your case, the server you downloaded from is known as `addons.mozilla.org`, and `mozilla.org` [is owned by](http://www.whois.net/whois/mozilla.org) the Mozilla Foundation.

Now, Mozilla *could* have bought a certificate that lists both domains as being valid for that single server (using the so-called [Subject Alternative Name](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SubjectAltName)). But I guess you just used an old domain, and Mozilla is expecting everyone to use the new one, and hence did not bother getting the old domain into the certificate as well.

So, next time?

- Even if there are no warnings, always check the URL. A browser might accept a certificate for, for example, `your-bank.something.com` *without warning you*. But then beware that you're really visiting a subdomain of `something.com`, not `your-bank.com`.
- If you do get a warning, check if the site that the browser says the certificate is valid for, is really the site you're actually looking for. If going to `your-bank.com` makes your browser warn you that the certificate is for `your-bank.something.com`, then ensure you can really trust `something.com`. This might indicate that DNS was somehow compromised, and your browser connected to the wrong server.

Comment: As an aside: note that https://addons.mozilla.com nicely redirects to the correct site. So, Mozilla *does* have a certificate for their `addons.mozilla.com` domain (though not for https://add-ons.mozilla.com), and maybe forgot to redirect the version with the additional dash, https://add-ons.mozilla.com. But in the world of DNS, *all* subdomains belong to the very same owner. So even `some.other.sub.sub.domain.mozilla.com` belongs to `mozilla.com` (and `secure.your-bank.something.com` really belongs to `something.com`).

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are trying to connect to `https://en-us.add-ons.mozilla.com` directly, but the certificate at that site on hand has this url on file:

`addons.mozilla.org`

All you need to do if you want to ensure security is simply go to `https://addons.mozilla.org` instead. It's the same site.

Comment: True, but then the question is: *"Downloaded a Firefox Addon [...] Should I worry?"*

Comment: @Arjan I don't know what `"Downloaded a Firefox Addon [...]"` means. But my guess here is - no - you don't have to worry.

Comment: I assume it means the question asker only started to worry *after* installing an addon from that other site. I agree they shouldn't worry too much, as the certificate seems legit and should not be accessible by the owner of another website. You might want to add that to your answer though.

Comment: @Arjan I think if the question asker meant that they had installed an addon and then got worried, they simply would of said that. To me it's unclear what `"Downloaded a Firefox Addon [...]"` means.  My guess actually is that they just typed `https://en-us.add-ons.mozilla.com` into a browser and got that warning not realizing every browser in the world including yours and mine, whether it's firefox or not, will receive the same untrusted error.

Comment: It might be good if you update your question to make a simple statement that, the website is a Mozilla, so based on that fact there is nothing to worry about.